# Stopping a thread after a client disconnects

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm having this problem where the thread that is used to get information from the client will not shutdown when that user has disconnected. The cpu usage goes up go to 100% and the program gets stuck in an infinite loop.

The problem is on the server side but I have searched and searched and I have found no way to solve this issue. I will post the whole server and client class but i think the issue is centered around the `Transfer` thread and the `SendToAll` method.

SERVER:

```
package serverSide;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Server implements Runnable{

    public final static int Port = 3000;
    public static ServerSocket ss;  
    public static ArrayList<ClientInfo> Client; 
    public static String Message = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Server server = new Server();
    }

    public Server() throws IOException{
        ss = new ServerSocket(Port);
        Client = new ArrayList<ClientInfo>();
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void run(){
        try {

            while (true){

                //Accept new client
                Socket s = ss.accept();

                //Get client info
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                String Name = dis.readUTF();

                //Give client storage
                int Result = CheckClients();
                if (Result == -1){
                    Result = Client.size();
                    Client.add(new ClientInfo(Name,Result,s));
                } else {
                    Client.set(Result, new ClientInfo(Name,Result,s));
                }
                //Run get input
                Transfer transfer = new Transfer(Client.get(Result).ClientID);
                transfer.start();

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Error");
        }
    }

    public static void SendToAll() throws IOException{
        for (int i=0;i<Client.size();i++){
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(Client.get(i).ClientSocket.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeUTF(Message);
        }
        Message = "";
    }

    public int CheckClients(){
        int Result = -1;
        for(int i = 0;i < Client.size() + 1;i++){
            try{
                if (Client.get(i) == null){
                    Result = i;
                    break;
                }
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                break;
            }
        }
        return Result;
    }

}

class Transfer extends Thread{

    int ClientNumber;

    public Transfer(int ClientNumber){
        this.ClientNumber = ClientNumber;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            DataInputStream dis;
            try {
                dis = new DataInputStream(Server.Client.get(ClientNumber).ClientSocket.getInputStream());
                String FromClient = dis.readUTF();
                Server.Message = FromClient;
                System.out.println(Server.Message);
                Server.SendToAll();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                try {
                    this.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

class ClientInfo {

    public ClientInfo(String Name,int ClientID,Socket ClientSocket){
        this.Name = Name;
        this.ClientID = ClientID;
        this.ClientSocket = ClientSocket;
    }

    public String Name;
    public int ClientID;
    public Socket ClientSocket;
}
```

CLIENT:

```
package clientSide;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Window.Type;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class ClientWindow {

    private JFrame frmClient;
    private JTextArea txtLog;
    private JTextField txtMessage;

    public String ServerAddress;
    public String Name;
    public String Password;
    public Socket s;
    public final int Port = 3000;

    public static void main(String[] args,String sa,String n,String p) {        

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ClientWindow window = new ClientWindow(sa,n,p);
                    window.frmClient.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void ConnectToServer(JTextArea txtLog){
        try {
            s = new Socket(ServerAddress,Port);
            System.out.println("Connected");

            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeUTF(Name);

            GetResponse gr = new GetResponse(txtLog,s);
            gr.start();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.frmClient,"Unable to open connection to " + ServerAddress + ". Unknown host.","Error" ,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.frmClient,"Unable to open connection to " + ServerAddress + ". Unknown host.","Error" ,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public ClientWindow(String sa,String n,String p) throws InterruptedException {
        ServerAddress = sa;
        Name = n;
        Password = p;
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frmClient = new JFrame();
        frmClient.setResizable(false);
        frmClient.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\joshu.DESKTOP-ECFG8JL\\workspace\\ChatSocket\\res\\icons\\Custom-Icon-Design-Flatastic-11-Connection.ico"));
        frmClient.setType(Type.POPUP);
        frmClient.setTitle("Connect");
        frmClient.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(15, 80, 120));
        frmClient.setBounds(100, 100, 870, 650);
        frmClient.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmClient.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        txtLog = new JTextArea();
        txtLog.setEditable(false);
        txtLog.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        txtLog.setFont(new Font("Calibri Light", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        txtLog.setColumns(1);
        txtLog.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 153, 255)));
        txtLog.setBackground(new Color(15, 80, 120));
        txtLog.setBounds(7, 87, 845, 450);
        frmClient.getContentPane().add(txtLog);

        txtMessage = new JTextField();
        txtMessage.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        txtMessage.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        txtMessage.setFont(new Font("Calibri Light", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        txtMessage.setColumns(1);
        txtMessage.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 153, 255)));
        txtMessage.setBackground(new Color(15, 80, 120));
        txtMessage.setBounds(7, 559, 659, 40);
        frmClient.getContentPane().add(txtMessage);

        JButton btnSend = new JButton("Send");
        btnSend.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DataOutputStream dos;
                try {
                    dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                    dos.writeUTF(Name + ": " + txtMessage.getText());
                    txtMessage.setText("");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnSend.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnSend.setFont(new Font("Calibri Light", Font.BOLD, 25));
        btnSend.setBackground(new Color(51, 153, 204));
        btnSend.setBounds(676, 559, 176, 40);
        Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
        btnSend.setBorder(emptyBorder);
        frmClient.getContentPane().add(btnSend);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setBackground(new Color(51, 153, 204));
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 864, 75);
        frmClient.getContentPane().add(panel);

        JLabel lblIP = new JLabel("Connected to: " + ServerAddress);
        lblIP.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        lblIP.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        lblIP.setForeground(new Color(15, 80, 120));
        lblIP.setFont(new Font("Calibri Light", Font.BOLD, 40));
        lblIP.setBounds(12, 12, 853, 50);
        panel.add(lblIP);

        ConnectToServer(txtLog);
    }
}

class GetResponse extends Thread{

    JTextArea txtLog;
    Socket s;

    public GetResponse(JTextArea txtLog,Socket s){
        this.txtLog = txtLog;
        this.s = s;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            try {
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                String Input = dis.readUTF();
                txtLog.setText(txtLog.getText() + "\n" + Input);
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Remove the line `this.join();` in the `run()` method of class `Transfer`. That will make the thread hang forever when an exception occurs. (It will make the thread wait until the thread itself stops, but it never stops because it's waiting for itself...).

Comment: I need away to stop the thread from within the thread itself. Do you know a way of doing this?

Comment: Just return from the `run()` method, that ends the thread.